Flea in six boxes
A flea is hiding in one of six boxes. To find the flea you can open a box (which cost \$1). If you did not guess correctly, after closing the box, the flea will jump randomly to a neighboring box to the left or right of its current box (if possible).
What is the. minimal cost that guarantees catching the flea, and what is the opening sequence?
If boxes are labeled 1..6, a sequence example is [1,3,6] at cost \$3. Problem have three versions:

simple case when the flea jumps D=1 box to left or right
the flea jumps a distance D, which can be any positive integer. It is always the same but we do not know it. If the flea does not have an available box at that distance to its left/right (eg D=10) it stays in its current box
we have an option to spray insecticide in the box after we open it. This is slightly more costly (an additional \$1, so \$2 together with opening) but blocks flea for jumping to that box in the future. The jump distance D is still unknown positive integer. Use a negative number in sequence if spraying, eg [ 2, -3, 6 ] at cost $4

Hints:

 1. cost is under 10
 2. cost is between 10 and 13
 3. cost is lower than in 2nd case


Are incomplete solutions (as community wikis) allowed?

To clarify, if the flea is at box 1 at the next turn it is guaranteed to jump to box 2? Or 50% probability it stays in place

yes, it is guaranteed that flea will jump to box 2 in that case. Flea must jump to other box if it is able to do it. Only case when it stays is if there is no available box to either side at distance D. That can happen if D is too large or even with D=1 in 3rd version of problem if eg you spray box 2 while flea was in box 1.

FYI, the D=1 case is a classic puzzle that has been discussed here a few times, for example here.

@JaapScherphuis yes, D=1 is classic puzzle ( although I did not find it here), but 2nd and 3rd question are  versions that I made since I did not see them elsewhere.

Cost for 1 is at most 6.

Case 1:

 A classic. The sequence [2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2] costs $8 and catches the flea.

 Red squares denote other possible positions of the flea.

Case 2 is surprisingly simple:

 The above solution catches the flea if D=1. If D=2 and the flea starts in an odd (resp. even) box, then the flea is in box 3 (resp. 4) every other round. The two times the above solution checks box 3 (resp. 4) occur an odd number of rounds apart, so the flea is always caught.


 For any higher D, the flea will either alternate between two boxes, or be stuck in one box. If either case brings it to boxes 2, 3, 4, or 5, it will be double-checked on alternate parities, and caught. The only fleas the Case 1 solution does not catch are either stuck in box 1, stuck in box 6, or alternating between those two boxes. Dealing with those cases yield the sequence [1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,6], costing $11.

Case 3:

 Consider all the fleas that alternate between two unsprayed boxes indefinitely, regardless of d. To catch one, one must either check one of its boxes on two different parities, or check both of its boxes on the same parity. We will prove that some parity must have every box checked on it, by induction. A corollary of this fact will be that N unsprayed boxes take at least 2N-1 rounds to check, which implies in turn that spraying cannot reduce the cost of checking six boxes below $11.


 The case of one box is trivial. Assuming the hypothesis is true for N boxes, consider the N+1'st box in the problem for N+1 boxes. By assumption, one parity contains N boxes, else not all of the fleas in the first N boxes are caught, and the other N-1 belong to the other parity. The N+1'st box must be checked at least once, to catch a flea that is stuck in the box: if it is checked only on the parity with N-1 boxes, then the flea jumping between box N+1 and the absent box will not be found, and so it must be checked on the parity with N boxes. This yields the hypothesis for N+1 boxes, completing the proof.


Correct for cases 1 and 2, not for case 3.

Nice @axiomatic, that is correct for cases 1 and 2.
Case 2 is indeed surprisingly simple for 6 boxes, which is why I selected that number, and your cost answer is correct and your sequence is optimal one (although not only optimal one, eg [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5,4,3,2]  ) .
Case 3 does have optimal strategy which include spraying, although in this case with 3 per spray it indeed has same 11 cost (with shorter sequence). But it will certainly need spraying to be optimal for larger N or lower cost since lowest N where spraying is mandatory part of optimal sequence depends on spray cost.

While your conclusion that spraying is never part of optimal solution is not correct, there are some cases ( depending on N and spray cost) where spraying is not optimal, and some where it does not lower cost but lower sequence length. Probable error in your reasoning is that N boxes need 2N-1 rounds without spray for case 2, which is only correct up to 6 boxes. Try it for 17 boxes like in problem that @Jaap linked above, and you will see that it needs much more ( although 7 boxes would be simplest example where 2N-1 stops working )

But it was my error in setting spray cost to 3(2+1) instead to 2(1+1), since my solution/Hint was based on 2 cost, and I will change question for case 3  accordingly.

BTW, I also realize that these multipart questions are problematic for marking answers, since you correctly answered cases 1 and 2, and had decent logic on case 3. It would be fully solved if you find optimal case 3 solution with new 2 cost or at least optimal (shorter) sequence with old 3 spray cost. It could also be considered as answer if no one else solves case 3.

Is this question supposed to cover all combinations of N and spray cost? My proof shows that you cannot use 3-cost sprays on 6 boxes, and 2-cost sprays don't reduce cost at all.

You can use cost 3 on 6 boxes - while it has same cost as without spray, it reduces optimal sequence length. And 2 cost spray reduces even optimal cost compared to not using spray.
Take note that your proof does not consider cost of spray at all, and it is trivial to prove that for low cost spray is optimal. Eg if spray cost 1, just doing [-1.-2.-3.-4.-5.-6] would cost 6 total, mush less than 11. If spray cost 1.5, just doing [-1.-2.-3.-4.-5. 6] would cost 8.5, still much less than 11.

For given spray cost 2, just doing [-1.-2.-3.-4.-5. 6] cost 11, so same as non spray ... but there is better sequence that uses spray at 2 per use and cost less than 11.

Case 3:
For a cost 10 solution:

 Spraying can be delayed until turn 6


 e.g. 4,4,6,6,2,-3,1,5,5
 - all numbers are checked for D>5
 - 4,5,6 are checked on both parities for D in {3,4,5}
 - 4 is checked on both parities and 1+5 after spraying 3 for D=2
 - for D=1, when 3 is sprayed:  the flea is not in 1, if in 2 it will be caught in 1, if in 4,5,6 it will be caught in 5

There are many cost 10 solutions however:

 Spray 3 in any order such that the 2 remaining distances are the same
 Then pick the middle one, spray another, pick the last
 There are 72 such solutions
 example -1,-2,-3,5,-4,6
 OR
 prevent a possible 'chain of 4' by spraying 3 or 4
 Pick 2 just before 3 or 5 just before 4 to
 - make sure the short side (that is not the middle of a 'chain of 3') is picked at the same parity
 - make sure that the spray does not block something that just got into already picked
 test the rest on both parities in any order
 There are 144 such solutions that spray on turn 2
 example 2,-3, 1,4,4,5,5,6,6
 example 5,-4, 3,2,2,1,6,3,1
 OR
 A combination of these strategies:
 spray 1 or 2 boxes randomly (except box3+4)
 then pick, spray, where the first pick is between the last spray and an unsprayed box X.
 test box X once (at correct parity) and the rest on both parities in any order

 example -2 5,-4, 3,1,6,3,1

I could not find a (easy) proof that cost 9 is impossible

Nice work, which demonstrate that using spray yield better solution than not using it.
But there are even better solutions with cost 9 ( using two sprayings )
